# My code doesn't show anything in terminal after compiling it

Tags: c++

My code doesn't show anything when I run it.
It's a simple linked list code.
I wrote it and it should print a result but it shows nothing when I run the program and here's the code so someone can review it.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *head = NULL;
struct node *current = NULL;

// display the list
void printlist(){
    struct node *p = head;
    cout << "\n[";

    //start from the beginning
    while(p != NULL) {
        cout << " "<< p->data << " ";
        p = p->next;
    }
    cout << "]";
}

//insertion at the beginning
void insertatbegin(int data){

    //create a link
    struct node *lk = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    lk->data = data;

    // point it to old first node
    lk->next = head;

    //point first to new first node
    head = lk;
}
void insertatend(int data){

    //create a link
    struct node *lk = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    lk->data = data;
    struct node *linkedlist = head;

    // point it to old first node
    while(linkedlist->next != NULL)
    linkedlist = linkedlist->next;

    //point first to new first node
    linkedlist->next = lk;
}
int main(){
    insertatbegin(12);
    insertatend(22);
    insertatend(30);
    insertatend(44);
    insertatend(50);
    cout << "Linked List: ";

    //print list
    printlist();
}
```

It should show

Linked List:

```
[ 12 22 30 44 50 ]
```

as I expect.

Comment: Why does this code use `struct node` everywhere?

Comment: ***my code doesn't show anything when i run it it's a simple linked list code*** Then it's time for you to install a debugger and step through your code line by line looking at the variables and flow after each individual line is executed.

Comment: Whenever you feel the need to do a C-style explicit conversion (a *cast*) like you do for the result of `malloc`, you should take it as a sign that you're probably are doing something wrong. In your case the main problem is that you are, basically, learning C and not C++.

Comment: Prefer `new` to `malloc`.  The `new` calls class constructors and is less letters to type.

Comment: You are not using anything from `<string>`, so get rid of it.  Next, compile as C program.

Comment: Are you trying to learn C or C++? These are two very different languages. Choose one and stick with it.

Comment: And on the note of not learning properly, please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/whats-the-problem-with-using-namespace-std)

Comment: Use a debugger and fix the memory access errors https://godbolt.org/z/zPMhGP93x

Comment: You should replace `current` with `tail`.  Your linked list is more efficient with a pointer to the last node, rather than having a `current` pointer that is not used.

Comment: Your `insertatend()` has undefined behavior if invoked as the first instruction.  Something about dereferencing a NULL pointer (e.g. `head`).

Comment: Yesterday someone posted: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @WIKI WIKI – Here a similar C-style, linked list that was posted in a [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78215784/22193627) today. It avoids memory leaks by including function `freelist`. You should, too.

Comment: When a student posts a question about a "C++" program that use more `C` than `C++`, the explanation is usually that he is in course that teaches both languages at the same time. If that is the case here, my advice is to write two solutions to each homework assignment, one using `C`, and the other, `C++`.

Answer (score 3):

You missed `lk->next = NULL;` in `void insertatend(int data)` in your C-style code.

You could do it properly in the real C++ with the default initializers and getting rid of `malloc` calls:

```
struct node {
    int data = 0;
    node *next = nullptr;
};
```

Answer (score -3):

you can check these step it may help you.
Flush the Output Buffer: You can manually flush the output buffer using std::flush after printing the list. Modify your printlist function like this:

```
    // display the list
void printlist(){
struct node *p = head;
cout << "\n[";

//start from the beginning
while(p != NULL) {
    cout << " "<< p->data << " ";
    p = p->next;
}
cout << "]\n" << std::flush; // here flush the output from buffer}
```

and in main function you have to call getchar()

```
int main(){
insertatbegin(12);
insertatend(22);
insertatend(30);
insertatend(44);
insertatend(50);
cout << "Linked List: ";

//print list
printlist();

getchar(); // Wait for a character input
return 0;
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).